# How is this trigonometric identify proven?

Tags: trigonometry

When researching answers to prove my identity
$$ \frac{\cos y}{1-\sin y} $$
I get to the point of
$$ \frac{1+\sin y}{\cos y} $$
Then it jumps straight to
$$ {\sec y} + {\tan y} $$
How do you prove that identity?

Comment: What you have written are not identities since no $=$ sign appears. Perhaps you could try and explain more carefully? Are you asking why is $\frac{1+\sin y}{\cos(y)}=\sec y + \tan y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\sec y=1/\cos y$ and $\tan y=\sin y/\cos y$, $$\frac{1+\sin y}{\cos y}=\frac{1}{\cos y}+\frac{\sin y}{\cos y}=\sec y+\tan y.$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am about to take a test, and this helped me tremendously